# Internal class type in typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to create internal class types in typescript ? Something like this:

```js
class Example<Data extends Record<string, any>> {
  type Key = keyof Data; // not allowed
  getKeys(): Key[] { ... }
}
```

This is possible within function blocks, for instance:

```js
function getKeys<Data extends Record<string, any>>(data: Data) {
  type Key = keyof Data; // allowed
  const keys: Key[] = Object.keys(data);
  return keys
}
```

The closest solution is to define a generic:

```js
class Example<Data extends Record<string, any>, Key = keyof Data> {
  getKeys(): Key[] { return [] }
}

const example = new Example<{aKey: 'value'}>();

const example2 = new Example<{aKey: 'value'}, "aKey">();
```

But :

- The type `key` could be overridden (because we only give a default value to `T`)
- Because it can be overridden, in a few case TS will complain if I assume the returned type to be `T` while not explicitly casting it.

Any clean solution or workaround ?

Comment: No, it is not possible. I think you are looking for [Associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html) which are supported in Rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK this is currently not possible: see [#7061: Permit type alias declarations inside a class](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7061)